# Do beavers make dams purely by instinct?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, animal-cognition

Do beavers use cognitive moves, learning, memory or skill acquisition in their life to build better? Or do they simply repeat instinctive gestures and end up with stereotyped architecture always?

Comment: [I mentioned this in Biology chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17128538#17128538). Might be worth migrating if you don't get any answers here within a week or so.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer related to beaver-specific behaviour or would your question also be satisfied by "how do spiders spin webs?"

Comment: Before I answer this, I want to know if it is, in any way, a homework-related question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that running water triggers some sort of instinct: 
http://juneauempire.com/stories/050408/out_275269543.shtml